# "to the extent that" vs "to the extent where"

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between:

> **To the extent where** education is concerned, no major issues were reported.
>
> **To the extent that** education is concerned, no major issues were reported.

?

Answer (score 1):

"To the extent where" sounds unnatural to me, and I would never say it. "To the extent that," on the other hand, is idiomatic, but I can't imagine a context in which I'd use the second sentence you've given as an example. I'd be likelier to say "where education is concerned, no major issues were reported" or – likelier still – "no major educational issues were reported."

Comment: Or "as far as education is concerned, ..".